# What is the difference between comma and comma?

Tags: c#, datatable, export-to-csv

I have to save the content of a `DataTable` to a `CSV` file. In the `DataTable` everything is fine, the data comes from an `SQL` query. However, if I open up the `CSV` in `Excel` I can see this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------+------+----+
|    DisplayName0     |     Publisher0      |             col3             | col4 | col5 |    |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------+------+----+
| Dropbox             | Dropbox, Inc.       | 432                          |  415 |   17 |    |
| Chef Client v12.4.3 | Chef Software       | Inc. <maintainers@chef.io>"" |  193 |  180 | 13 |
| Cisco AnyConnect    | Cisco Systems, Inc. | 836                          |  824 |   12 |    |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------+------+----+
'Dropbox, Inc.' -> 'Dropbox, Inc.' //this is good
'Cisco Systems, Inc.' -> 'Cisco Systems, Inc.' //this is good too
'"Chef Software, Inc. <maintainers@chef.io>"' -> 'Chef Software' and ' Inc. <maintainers@chef.io>""' //what happened here?
```

My good old piece of code for exporting `DataTable` to `CSV` is:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dlg3.FileName);

string strHeader = "";
for (int s = 0; s < tbl.Columns.Count; s++)
{
    strHeader += "\"" + tbl.Columns[s].ColumnName + "\",";
}
streamWriter.WriteLine(strHeader);

for (int m = 0; m < tbl.Rows.Count; m++)
{
    string strRowValue = "";
    for (int n = 0; n < tbl.Columns.Count; n++)
    {
        if (tbl.Rows[m][n].ToString() != "")
        {
            strRowValue += "\"" + tbl.Rows[m][n] + "\",";
        }
        else
        {
            strRowValue += tbl.Rows[m][n] + ",";
        }
    }
    streamWriter.WriteLine(strRowValue);
}
streamWriter.Close();
```

So the question is why the comma in the dropbox one is not "generating" a new cell, but in the chef client one does?

Comment: This is why I add `"` before and after every single cell value. Based on this Excel usually escapes everything, but now.

Comment: Please use a proper Csv nuget package instead.

Comment: This might be clearer if you included the text your program generates (rather than your interpretation of how Excel interprets that text).

Comment: Voted to close as TYPO

Comment: @Drew Why? "Put on hold as unclear what you're asking" Unclear? I still think that my question is crystal clear?

Comment: I disagreed with the prevailing close reason that my name would be attached to. So I left the comment above. See my answer here on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310483/i-dont-know-how-type-questions/310511#310511)

Comment: TYPO / Cannot be reproduced / not of great benefit to future readers / localized

Comment: @Drew Fair enough, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That peace of string got doublequoted.
You could check if the string allready starts and ends with quotation before adding that.

```
if(!tbl.Rows[m][n].StartsWith("\"") && !tbl.Rows[m][n].EndsWith("\""))
strRowValue += tbl.Rows[m][n] + ",";
else
strRowValue += "\"" + tbl.Rows[m][n] + "\",";
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) But even a quote on one side and not the other will gum things up, although that is less likely to happen.

Comment: You're right. Though I simply solved by using `tbl.Rows[m][n].ToString().Trim('"')`, as I don't need that in the export. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a double quote after the problem data: ""

Looks like you might have quotes in your data, then you are adding quotes when you output the data, so you end up with this in your file:

```
""Chef Software, Inc. <maintainers@chef.io>""
```